# Is there any way to assign several sources to one assertion in soapUI?

Tags: soapui, assertion

Is there any way to assign several sources to one assertion in soapUI 4.5.1? For example i need to check all services responses if they contain some element.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is groovy script assertion.

I have no idea what exactly you're trying to assert but groovy is going to be the way to go to accomplish this.